# How to define variable for Trac TicketQuery?

Tags: agile, trac, sprint

Using TRAC **TicketQuery template for sprint** to show what's going on. How would I type name of current sprint only ONCE, when template needs it in multiple location? For example "Sprint1" is needed is 6 places:

> = New items = [[TicketQuery(milestone=**Sprint1**,status=new,format=table,order=priority,col=id|summary|priority|component|owner|type)]]
>
> = Items in progress = [[TicketQuery(milestone=**Sprint1**,status=in_progress,format=table,order=priority,col=id|summary|priority|component|owner|type)]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will do something close to what you want?  (It will group by status value, so you should only need 1 query instead of 6.)

```
[[TicketQuery(milestone=Sprint1,format=table,order=priority,col=id|summary|priority|component|owner|type,group=status)]]
```

As for defining variables like that, no, there isn't a way to do that.

Comment: If I can define ORDER of grouping, then it might work. Would that be possible? Besides changing status values to so that they group in right order by default...

Comment: I don't see a way to specify the order of the groups, sorry.

Comment: Well, I can always rename status values to start with numbers :) Thanx, you've been a great help!